# Doing a make over TRAMP

Tags: emacs, makefile, tramp

I am using Emacs Tramp for remote development.  I think something must be wrong.  I had some serious issues with speed when I used `ssh:`, so I switched to `scp:`.  It seems to work much faster.  I tried to run `M-x compile` with `make` and it seems to act differently than if I run make directly from a shell prompt.  Namely, it is unable to find .h files.  It compiles fine from a shell prompt.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try using the 'scpc' method. If your system supports ssh "Control Master" (not possible under Cygwin, in case that's relevant), this will *dramatically* improve the speed of TRAMP. 'rsyncc' is the other default method which tries to utilise that feature. I don't know what the 'make' issue is, but check that your `tramp-remote-process-environment` variable is sensible, and `M-x customize-group tramp RET` to check out available tramp configuration in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `M-x tramp-compile` explicitly. The keybindings for compilation are automatically remapped when you're editing a remote file with TRAMP, but `M-x compile` may be operating on the local copy of the files.  ?